# Where can I add my custom curl code in prestashop file?

Tags: prestashop

I want to add my **curl** code in prestashop file after completing the payment made by customer. I want this for all payment gateways.

Answer (score 0):

We must put it in the order-confirmation.tpl

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

you can create a custom module and register order confirmation hook, and place your curl request code inside the hook function

```
function hookOrderConfirmation($params)    { 
 // your curl code goeas here
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, please may you tell me in which file i add this function?

Comment: create a custom module, go to prestashop online module generator tool and create a simple module as 1,2,3 and modify as per your requirement